# hwi oauth bundle and Symfony 4.2 : Impossible to install

Tags: symfony, oauth, composer-php, symfony4

I am trying to intall HWI oauth bundle with symfony 4.2 but it is not working.
I follow the step described : https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md but it doesn't work.

Below the composer output :

```
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle
Using version ^0.6.3 for hwi/oauth-bundle
Using version ^2.0 for php-http/guzzle6-adapter
Using version ^1.14 for php-http/httplug-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.2.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.3
    - php-http/client-common v1.6.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common v1.4.2 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common v1.4.1 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common v1.4.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common 1.5.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common 1.3.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.6.3 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.6.3, 0.6.x-dev].
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.x-dev requires php-http/client-common ^1.3 -> satisfiable by php-http/client-common[1.3.0, 1.5.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.x-dev, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.6.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.7.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.8.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.8.1 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.8.2 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.9.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.x-dev requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/httplug v1.1.0

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

PS : at the end of my composer.json I add :

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

composer require hwi/oauth-bundle --ignore-platform-reqs

```
Using version ^0.6.3 for hwi/oauth-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.2.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.x-dev requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.3 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.6.3 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.6.3, 0.6.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

composer require hwi/oauth-bundle php-http/guzzle6-adapter php-http/httplug-bundle --ignore-platform-reqs

```
Using version ^0.6.3 for hwi/oauth-bundle
Using version ^2.0 for php-http/guzzle6-adapter
Using version ^1.14 for php-http/httplug-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.2.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.3
    - php-http/client-common v1.6.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common v1.4.2 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common v1.4.1 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common v1.4.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common 1.5.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - php-http/client-common 1.3.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^2.6 || ^3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.6.3 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.6.3, 0.6.x-dev].
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.x-dev requires php-http/client-common ^1.3 -> satisfiable by php-http/client-common[1.3.0, 1.5.0, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.x-dev, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.6.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.7.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.8.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.8.1 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.8.2 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.9.0 requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - php-http/client-common 1.x-dev requires php-http/httplug ^1.1 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.1.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/httplug v1.1.0
```

Comment: composer req hwi/oauth-bundle --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work. I edited my post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1457#issuecomment-449733824, you could try the following:

```
composer require php-http/guzzle6-adapter:^1.1
composer require php-http/httplug-bundle
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried without succes, but your answer makes me try another way to install by modifying composer.json and specifying all versions : "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.6.3",
"php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "~1.1.1",
"php-http/httplug-bundle": "~1.13" . And it works ! (php : 7.2, symfony 4.2). Thank you Nico !

Answer (score 3):

I answer my own question to help if anybody has the same issue. I have written this in Nico's answer comment but it is not easy to read.

I solve my problem by adding in my composer.json :

```
"hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.6.3",
"php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "~1.1.1",
"php-http/httplug-bundle": "~1.13"
```

Then I perform a

```
composer update
```

and all has been installed and works !

Comment: What did you answer when Symfony asked to run a recipe?


```Do you want to execute this recipe?
    [y] Yes
    [n] No
    [a] Yes for all packages, only for the current installation session
    [p] Yes permanently, never ask again for this project
    (defaults to n): n```

Comment: This answer inspired me this other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778870/composer-could-not-resolve-dependencies-for-hwi-oauth-bundle