# composer could not resolve dependencies for hwi/oauth-bundle

Tags: composer-php, symfony4, dependency-management, php-7.2, hwioauthbundle

If I do `$ composer require hwi/oauth-bundle` I get this:

```
Using version ^0.6.3 for hwi/oauth-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.2.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for hwi/oauth-bundle ^0.6.3 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[0.6.3].
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.3 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v2.0.1].
    - hwi/oauth-bundle 0.6.3 requires php-http/httplug ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v1.0.0, v1.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v2.0.0, v1.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: php-http/httplug[v2.0.0, v1.1.0].
    - php-http/guzzle6-adapter v2.0.1 requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove php-http/httplug v2.0.0

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My PHP version is:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2019 17:05:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

And this is my current `composer.json`:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.4",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.2.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

My symfony version is:

```
$ php bin/console --version
Symfony 4.2.4 (env: dev, debug: true)
```

## Question

How can I install `hwi/oauth-bundle` in a SF `v4.2.4` and with PHP `v7.2.15`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a dupe of this: [hwi oauth bundle and Symfony 4.2 : Impossible to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081927/hwi-oauth-bundle-and-symfony-4-2-impossible-to-install)

The answer of Luc of adding this worked fine for me

```
"hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.6.3",
"php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "~1.1.1",
"php-http/httplug-bundle": "~1.13"
```

In fact what I did is requiring them from the command line with this command:

```
composer require "hwi/oauth-bundle:^0.6.3" "php-http/guzzle6-adapter:~1.1.1" "php-http/httplug-bundle:~1.13"
```

Then when asked `Do you want to execute this recipe?` (twice, one for `hwi/oauth-bundle` and the other for `php-http/httplug-bundle`) what I did is to tell `n` and follow the recipe manually from here: https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/hwi/oauth-bundle/0.6

I added the routing file (import of routing) here https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/blob/master/hwi/oauth-bundle/0.6/config/routes/hwi_oauth_routing.yaml and the package file (configuration) here https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/blob/master/hwi/oauth-bundle/0.6/config/packages/hwi_oauth.yaml

Then I added the bundles modifying my `bundles.php` and then finally used the `manifest.json` and `post-install.txt` in the recipe root to help me have a nice configuration (including the `.env` suggestion which I had to change as I did not want to use Facebook but Google's one.

Same with the recipe here https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/php-http/httplug-bundle/1.6 for the HttpPlug. Just added the package config file.